# Cluster of forward proxies

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I'm trying to figure out whether Docker Swarm or Kubernetes are a good choice for my use case.

Basically, I want to build a small cluster of forward proxies (via squid, nginx or a custom nodejs script), and be able to deploy/start/stop/purge them all together.

I should be able to access the proxy cluster via a single IP address, manager should be able to load-balance the request to a node, and each proxy node must use a unique outgoing IP address.

I'm wondering:

1. Are Docker Swarm and/or Kubernetes the right way to go about it?
2. If so, should I set-up Docker Swarm and/or Kubernetes and its worker nodes (running the proxy) on a single dedicated server or separate virtual servers?
3. Is it also possible for all the cluster nodes to share a file system storage for caching, common config etc.
4. Any other tips to get this working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Docker running in swarm mode should work well for this
2. Run docker on a single dedicated server; I see no need for virtual servers. You could also run the swarm across multiple dedicated servers.
3. [https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/](http://Secrets) work well for some settings and configurations. If you require significant storage, simply add a database service to your cluster

Docker swarm mode fits your requirements quite well; requests are automatically balanced across your swarm and each service instance can be configured to have a unique address. You should check out the swarm mode tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks! That will help to get started.